# Press more than one button at the same time in multitouch application

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

My WPF application has more than one button, supports multitouch but doesn't apply pressed style to the pressed buttons. To be more specific:

- I touch the first button, the tunneling happens correctly (I've bound IsPressed Button property to a Trigger which applies a style)
- I touch the second button without releasing the first one, the code behind catches the raised event correctly, but in this case the template is not applied.

Note: the buttons are two instances of the same class and work correctly when pressed once at time. The code is pretty simple:

```
<Button Focusable="False" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}" Grid.Row="{Binding GridRow}" Margin="{Binding Margin}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"  Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False" Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False" >
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="TouchDown">
           <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ButtonDownCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TouchUp">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ButtonUpCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

And the applyed style:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
       <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="glass" Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource PressedShadow}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="glass" Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
                <Setter TargetName="blink" Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource PressedShadow}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="blink" Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
 </MultiDataTrigger>
```

Ideas?